# Why a Trait extending Abstract Class with non-empty constructor compiles?

Tags: scala, inheritance, constructor, traits

Traits cannot have constructor arguments. So how is it possible to write a trait which extends and abstract class which has a non-empty constructor?

```
abstract class HasConsArgs(val i: Int)
trait Test extends HasConsArgs
```

Which compiles. But when trying to use;

```
new Test {}
```

You get a error `not enough arguments for constructor HasConsArgs: ...`... Why is this the case, is it possible to have an implementer of a trait call this constructor somehow?

```
class Impl(i: Int) extends Test //doesnt work
```

Fails with `error: not enough arguments for constructor HasConsArgs: (i: Int)HasConsArgs.` which means that I probably need to have `Impl` extend the `HasConsArgs` abstract class...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, you cannot create an anonymous class using `Test`, because you cannot specify the super constructor arguments, as you've seen.

If a trait extends a class, all the classes that mixin the trait has to be either a subclass of that class or a descendant class of that class.

```
class A
class B extends A
class C
trait D extends A
class E extends D
class F extends A with D
class G extends B with D
class H extends C with D   // fails
```

In order to mixin `Test` trait, you can write

```
class Impl(i: Int) extends HasConstArgs(i) with Test
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference between a `subclass` and a `descendant` class?

Comment: @NightWolf ah, descendant class is still subclass really. Maybe I should use subclass only. `class A; class B extends A; trait C extends A; class E extends B with C;`. B is a *direct* subclass of A while E is a *direct* subclass of B which extends A. E is a descendant of A in the type hierarchy.